# Identify references within same workbook vs references in other workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have Excel VBA code to color the font based on the parameters below:

- Blue: hard-coded numbers
- Black: formulas (ex. sum, vlookup, average, etc)
- Green: number that is linked from another sheet within the same file
- Red: number that is linked from another sheet from an exterior file

I have written the code below but it does not distinguish between a reference from another cell/sheet within the same file versus a reference in an exterior file. Any help would be great to complete this last step.

Thanks

```
Dim rng As Range, rErr As Range

On Error Resume Next

For Each rng In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)

    If rng.HasFormula Then

        Set rErr = Range(Mid(rng.Formula, 2, Len(rng.Formula) - 1))

        If CBool(Err) Then

            rng.Font.ColorIndex = 1 'black

        Else

            rng.Font.ColorIndex = 3 'red

        End If

        Err = 0

    ElseIf CBool(Len(rng.Value)) Then

        rng.Font.ColorIndex = 5 'blue

    Else

        rng.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic 'default

    End If

Next rng

Set rErr = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Font.ColorIndex = 5 'blue

        For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
            Select Case True
                Case InStr(cell.Formula, "[") > 0
                    cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 'red
                Case InStr(Replace(cell.Formula, cell.Parent.Name & "!", ""), "!") > 0
                    cell.Font.ColorIndex = 4  'green
                Case Else
                    cell.Font.ColorIndex = 1 'black
            End Select
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @antd, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd to me that linked cells are so hard to find ... but they really are.

You can't just search for `[]` because a manually typed link could leave them out and the link could still work. You can't just search for a filename because two files with the same name could exist in different folders. You can't just search for a file path or `\` because if the linked workbook is open in the same Excel application, the filepath is omitted from the link.

Internal links pose similar issues. You can't rely on searching for a `!` because the link might be a `Name`, for example.

Some time ago, I had to identify internally and externally linked cells, so I wrote some rough and ready code to do it. Those functions are included in the sample below but I've no doubt there'll be exceptions (for example, any formula containing the same string as the name of the `Name` will fail the test).

I've kept the functions as separate routines as they might be useful to other users, but it does make the code for your project slightly inefficient. May prove to be something you can work off though.

You'll note I've just used `UsedRange` to define the target range - you might want to amend this.

```
Sub RunMe()
    Dim extLinkCells As Range
    Dim intLinkCells As Range
    Dim formulaCells As Range
    Dim numberCells As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set numberCells = Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set extLinkCells = AllExternallyLinkedCells(Sheet1.UsedRange)
    Set intLinkCells = AllInternallyLinkedCells(Sheet1.UsedRange)
    'Pick up the remaining non-linked cells (ie must just be formulas)
    For Each cell In Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        If Intersect(cell, extLinkCells) Is Nothing And Intersect(cell, intLinkCells) Is Nothing Then
            If formulaCells Is Nothing Then
                Set formulaCells = cell
            Else
                Set formulaCells = Union(formulaCells, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    numberCells.Font.Color = vbBlue
    formulaCells.Font.Color = vbBlack
    intLinkCells.Font.Color = vbGreen
    extLinkCells.Font.Color = vbRed
End Sub

Private Function AllInternallyLinkedCells(testRange As Range) As Range

    Dim result As Range, cell As Range
    Dim links() As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = testRange.Parent.Parent

    'Acquire all sheet names apart from this one
    i = 1
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> testRange.Worksheet.Name Then
            ReDim Preserve links(1 To i)
            links(i) = ws.Name
            Debug.Print "Internal Link"; i; links(i)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    'Acquire all names that don't refer to this sheet
    For Each nm In wb.Names
        If nm.RefersToRange.Worksheet.Name <> testRange.Worksheet.Name Then
            ReDim Preserve links(1 To i)
            links(i) = nm.Name
            Debug.Print "Internal Link"; i; links(i); " of "; nm.RefersToRange.Worksheet.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    'Test if cell formula matches our list
    For Each cell In testRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        If Exists(cell.Formula, links) Then
            If result Is Nothing Then
                Set result = cell
            Else
                Set result = Union(result, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set AllInternallyLinkedCells = result

End Function

Private Function AllExternallyLinkedCells(testRange As Range) As Range

    Dim result As Range, cell As Range
    Dim rawLinks As Variant
    Dim adjLinks() As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    'Acquire all the links
    rawLinks = ThisWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    ReDim adjLinks(1 To UBound(rawLinks) * 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(rawLinks)
        fileName = Right(rawLinks(i), Len(rawLinks(i)) - InStrRev(rawLinks(i), "\"))
        Set wb = Nothing: On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks(fileName): On Error GoTo 0
        adjLinks(i) = IIf(wb Is Nothing, rawLinks(i), fileName)
        adjLinks(i + 1) = Replace(adjLinks(i), fileName, "[" & fileName & "]")
        Debug.Print "External Link"; i; adjLinks(i + 1)
    Next

    For Each cell In testRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        If Exists(cell.Formula, adjLinks) Then
            If result Is Nothing Then
                Set result = cell
            Else
                Set result = Union(result, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set AllExternallyLinkedCells = result

End Function

Private Function Exists(item As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If InStr(item, arr(i)) > 0 Then
            Exists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```